Mathematical definition of a time averaged series
I am asking on how to interpret this notation. I am reading a paper discussion diffusion measurements from a mean-squared-displacement. The notation is as follows:
The main measurement is a trajectory $\vec x_1, \dots \vec x_n$. T
$\Delta x_n$ is a vector of displacement with seperation of $n$. For example, $\Delta x_1$ is the series of displacements 1 time step apart.
The MSD is defined as the series average of each time-step separation, squared:
$$\langle (\Delta x_n)^2\rangle = \frac{1}{N-n}\sum_{i=0}^{N-n}(x_{i+n}-x_i)^2$$
This is intuitive and is a simple average of the series.
Now, I am unclear what the following definition tries to state:
$$\overline {(\Delta x_n)^2}$$

where $\overline\dots$ denotes averages over the time series $\Delta x_1, \dots, \Delta x_n$.

I am very confused at this definition and am unclear how it is different from the series average.
I would be grateful for a clear mathematical response. I chose this thread as this is less mathmatics/physics rather than a statistical definition.
Thanks

Notationally $\overline {(\Delta x_n)^2}$ and $\langle (\Delta x_n)^2\rangle$ look as if they may be intended to have similar meanings. You might check whether it is supposed to be a simple average of the data: it looks to me as if there might be $N-n+1$ squared differences (over gaps of $n$) being summed but it is being divided by $N-n$, so perhaps this has a Bessel correction.
